# Transforming an array into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Is there any elegant way to transform a flat array into array of objects like on eg. below?

@300, 60 etc. are sum of the same values in array

```
const array = [100, 100, 100, 30, 30, 20]

const transformed = [{100: 300}, {30: 60}, {20: 20}]
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce` is useful here. Keep a dictionary of seen numbers, and as a value the accumulated sum of its occurrences.

Comment: Its hard for me to tell what exactly you are asking. for example where did the "300" and "60" come from?

Comment: @Rick Its actually a sum of same values in array. I forget to mention it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine consecutive equal numbers, you can loop while keeping track of the previous number.

```js
const array = [100, 100, 100, 30, 30, 20];
const res = [];
let o, prev;
for(const x of array){
  if(prev === x){
    o[x] += x;
  } else {
    res.push(o = {[x]: x});
  }
  prev = x;
}
console.log(res);
```

If you want the sum of all numbers with the same value, you can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store each sum.

```js
const array = [100, 100, 100, 30, 30, 20];
const res = Object.values(array.reduce((acc,x)=>(
  (acc[x]=acc[x] || {[x]:0})[x]+=x, acc
), {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's actually pretty similar to what I have been trying to achive. Thanks :D

Comment: @smate12 No problem. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless of the input array being sorted:

```js
const array = [100, 100, 100, 30, 30, 20];
const grouped = {};
array.map(function(item) {
    if (grouped[item]) {
        grouped[item] += item;
    } else {
        grouped[item] = item;
    }
})

const groupedArray = Object.keys(grouped).map(function (key, index) {
    const result = {};
    result[key] = grouped[key];
    return result;
});

console.log(groupedArray)
```